# IIS 10 URL Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS redirect on same port

Tags: windows, iis, redirect, rewrite, url

I would like an easy redirect but doesn't work. Original: *http://exwebsite.com:8084* to Redirect: *https://exwebsite.com:8084* Can u help me? The simple `<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />` and `...url="https: // {HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"...` work correctly for simple http://exwebsite.com redirect to https://exwebsite.com but the custom port redirect doesn't and I dont know why. I tried this: [(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PmUp.png)

Comment: You can only host HTTP or HTTPS at TCP port 8084, not both. So literally the rule you wrote is invalid. When no port is specified, HTTP goes to port 80 and HTTPS goes to port 443.

Comment: Thank you the fast answer! So how can I solved this problem? I operate some service on my Windows Server e.g. plex or torrent clients on different ports and I want if the user write the simple http url with the service port than redirect it to https site with the same port. Can u help me how can I solve this with URL rewrite or other way?